# How to set custom dialer as default on Nexus 5?

Tags: phone-app, 4.4-kitkat, nexus-5

I have a Nexus 5 with root permissions. Google Dialer annoys me. I installed [ExDialer & Contacts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.modoohut.dialer). How to set this Dialer as my default dialer?

I will welcome any advice.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I'm actually kind of confused by your question; I think this would be as simple as replacing the blue "Phone" app icon on your homescreen with the "Dialer" app. I just installed ExDialer & Contacts and that method works for me. Have you found some case where it automatically brings up the Google dialer?

Comment: I would imagine an incoming call would be the issue. Can you go into Settings > Applications and remove the defaults for the stock dialer / phone? Or does your EX Dialer have an option in settings to make default / surpress stock?

Comment: @dotVezz, thanks for the answer. I replaced the standard icon on the icon of the new application. However, I do not know whether there is an option in the settings of operating system that set up the standard dialer. For example, I can install my custom keyboard. Fortunately, I have not had any problems yet.  I'm worried because android implemented service architecture (Intents) and I do not understand where other applications will be addressed.

Comment: @RossC, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I can not remove the defaults for the stock dialer. This button is not active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't hard.First,you need to disable phone by defaults.go to "manage app",select phone...clear defaults.then go to the menu,remove the phone icon and replace with the exdialer...then i think it should be easy from there on....any where you get a prompt select the exdialer